# How to add a PFRelation between 2 PFUsers?

Tags: parse-platform, pfuser, pfrelation

I want to have a relation between user A and user B ?
Do you have an full working example for this ?

Thanks very much :)

Comment: This is not the place to have others do the work for you. If you have tried something please include the code and make a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It is in the documentation https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-relational-data